# Padding before TextField Icon

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, padding, textfield

I got the way to apply an icon just before the `textfield` starts programmatically but the main concern was that to apply padding just before the icon.

As it is just touching the border of the textfield.

I program it like below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Email Icon on left of email Text Field
    let imageView1 = UIImageView()
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "Message.png")
    imageView1.image = image1
    imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 10, 10)
    emailTextField.leftView = imageView1
    emailTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

    // Password Icon on left of pass Text Field
    let imageView2 = UIImageView()
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "Lock.png")
    imageView2.image = image2
    imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 10, 10)
    passwordTextField.leftView = imageView2
    passwordTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

}
```

But all the way space between the border and the icon is very less.

Is there any way to make a padding between them?

Please let me know if there is any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Try creating a UIView(say **contentView**) and a UIImageView(say **leftImage**)
2. Set *leftImage* frame as it is aligned 10 points away from *contenView*'s **x**(i.e) if *contentView*'s frame is (0, 0, 25, 20) then set *leftImage*'s frame as (10, 0, 15, 20)
3. Then add *leftImage* as subview to *contentView*
4. Now it's simple add *contentView* as leftView of textfield.

   ```
   let leftImage = UIImageView()

   let image1 = UIImage(named: "Key")
   leftImage.image = image1

   let contentView = UIView()
   contentView.addSubview(leftImage)

   contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20)
   leftImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 25, 20)

   passwordTextField.leftView = contentView
   passwordTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
   ```

   **Previops output:**

   [image]

   **Final Output:**

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take one `UIView` of width 20 and you can add `leftVeiw` to this view. Now set this view as `leftView`.

Answer (score 0):

you can easy to adjust the space by inherit the`UITextField`

```
class field: UITextField {

override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect = bounds
    rect.origin.x -= 10
    return rect
}

override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect = bounds
    rect.origin.x -= 10
    return rect
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You simply do this in one line**

```
textfield.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var passTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let emailImage = UIImage(named:"email")
        addLeftImageTo(txtfield: emailTextfield, andImage:emailImage!)
        
        let passwordImage = UIImage(named:"password")
        addLeftImageTo(txtfield: passTextfield, andImage:passwordImage!)
    }

    func addLeftImageTo(txtfield:UITextField,andImage img:UIImage) {
        let leftImageView=UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:10, y: 0, width: 25, height: 20))
        leftImageView.image=img
        
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 20))
       view.addSubview(leftImageView)
        
        txtfield.leftView=view
        txtfield.leftViewMode = .always
```